# Sign convention of work

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, conventions

I am studying about reversible steady-flow work, and the author of the book states that  Taking the positive direction of work to be from the system (work output) the energy balance of a steady-flow device undergoing an internally reversible process is:

```
                      q_rev - w_rev = dh + dke + dpe
```

But, if work output is taken as positive, please explain why do we use a negative sign to denote the work output in the equation above when it should be positive?

The same question also holds for general conservation of energy principle where:

```
                        E_in - E_out = ΔE_system
               q_in - q_out + w_in - w_out = ΔE_system (control mass)
```

shouldn't w_out be positive?

Comment: If outgoing work is taken as positive, and we’re interested in the system, then the loss of energy from outgoing work corresponds to a negative number, yes?

Comment: More on [sign conventions of work in thermodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermodynamics+conventions+work).

Comment: @Chemomechanics but the textbook states that the work done "from the system" is taken as positive, doesn't it mean means W_system > 0 and W_surr < 0. I intuitively understand when the system does work its internal energy decreases, but these phrasings like 'taking work output as positive' and  above sign conventions are confusing the heck out of me. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But, if work output is taken as positive, please explain why do we use
> a negative sign to denote the work output in the equation above when
> it should be positive?

If work is positive (work done ***by*** the system ***on*** the surroundings) energy is transferred out of the system. Thus the change in energy in the system is negative. The negative sign in the equation assures us that substituting a positive number for $W$ in the equation results in a negative change in the energy of the system.

If work is negative (work done ***on*** the system ***by*** the surroundings) energy is transferred into the system. Thus the change in energy in the system is positive. The negative sign in the equation assures us that substituting a negative number for $W$ in the equation results in a positive change in the energy of the system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I finally understand the sign convention for work.